# What's the "didMove#to" for SKSpriteNode?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

Of course, in a scene...

```
class DotScene: SKScene {
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        print("this scene is now in place...")
```

you know the scene is in place when `didMove#to` is called.

(It's just like ViewDidAppear, you could say.)

## However

I have no clue how to know that a **sprite** has been added to a scene.

```
class Spaceship: SKSpriteNode {
    
    func wtf() {
        
        this sprite has just been added to a scene
        (such as with .childNode)
        this sprite is now in place in the scene ...
```

There simply - has to be - a call that alerts you that a node has appeared on the scene successfully.

What is it ?

Comment: There is no quick way,  you can try to observe when `scene` is not nil using key value observation (KVO) if you need to determine when a node is added to a scene, of course, you should always know when you are adding to a scene since you need to call `addChild(:_)` or `moveToParent(_:)`, but I can see the need for when your sprite needs to know it

Comment: It's - unbelievable - they forgot this.  It would be exactly as if viewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear did not exist in UIKit.  Sure - you could, instead, observe on the parent views and send down the message (ROFL).  It's an ........ incredible, astounding mistake.  Apple's entire SpriteKit is absolutely magnificent; this is the most hilarious omission, ever, in iOS.  Again it is literally just as if they had "forgot" viewDidLoad over on view controllers!  Goodness!

Comment: no, it is by design.  UIKit is based on an MVC architecture, so you are not suppose to be doing code inside of the  View class,  SpriteKit is not MVC

Comment: Nah, they forgot.  SpriteKit is apple's attempt a moving towards an ECS system.  It's literally impossible to subclass SKSpriteNode without having let's say initialization code, once it's on the scene.  The central most basic thing you need in the entire, total nature of their move to behaviour based agents - they forgot it  :)

Comment: GameplayKit is Apples attempt to ECS, not SpriteKit

Comment: The fact is you just have to add a "setup" call, and just call that explicitly from the parent after you .didAdd.  It's not the end of the world and many ECS game engines want you to explicitly do that, it's just a bit .. oddball

Comment: what?  addAction ....  I'm not sober enough to discuss that one with you my man  :)  in any event if you're pretty confident there is *no such thing* as I'm asking - and thanks for that (wish I had asked 3 hours ago! :)  ) you oughta put that in as an answer man ..

Comment: and i just learned you can't resize a circle collider, good grief! :)  @Knight0fDragon

Comment: a circle collider?  Make a new question about it so that we are not just conversing about something off topic.

Comment: you can't resize a physicsBody on the fly - you have to just make a new one.  @Knight0fDragon

Comment: If you scale your SKNode, the physics body will scale,  other than that, no you can't reshape a body on the fly

Comment: right ........ @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Would be a nice feature to add,  would make animations a lot easier

Comment: right, no kidding !  the fact that you CAN resize the sprite itself (you can set .size freely) is a bit odd; maybe they should have limited both.  Anyway.

Comment: did KoD's answer solve this for you?

Comment: hi @Fluidity - not sure what you mean?  (it's normal on SO to wait a few days before ticking an answer, particularly if there's a bounty, just to give others a chance)

Comment: I meant did you still need help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SpriteKit there is no way to detect inside of a custom sprite class when a node is added to a scene.  This is has been left out because you have control when a sprite is added to a scene via `addChild` or `moveToParent`.

Spritekit does not conform to an MVC architecture, where as UIKit does.  One of the reasons `didMoveToView` exists is because the purpose of the View is to be an output display only.  The controller is responsible for handling the code behind for the View.  Now the view controller can be used to call `presentScene` from view, but if we are transitioning, we really have no idea at what point the scene is officially attached to the view.  (There are other reasons besides this, I am just giving one example)

Now to get around this issue, you may be able to implement Key Value Observing (KVO), and listen to when `scene` gets set.  To do this, simply do:

```
override init()
{
    super.init()
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(SKNode.scene), options: [.old, .new, .initial], context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) 
{
    if keyPath == #keyPath(SKNode.scene) && self.scene != nil 
    {
        didAttachToScene()
    }
}

func didAttachToScene()
{
}

deinit 
{
    removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(SKNode.scene))
}
```

Now, I have not tested this,  I am currently in a windows environment, but if this does not work, you can listen to when a node is attached to a parent (which I have actually done with KVO so I know it is possible), and infer if we are on a scene that way since a node must have a parent to even qualify being on a scene.

```
override init()
{
    super.init()
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(SKNode.parent), options: [.old, .new, .initial], context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) 
{
    if keyPath == #keyPath(SKNode.parent) && self.scene != nil 
    {
        didAttachToScene()
    }
}

func didAttachToScene()
{
}

deinit 
{
    removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(self.parent))
}
```

Comment: Good one, for googlers here we now know for the record there **IS NO** such call at the SKSpriteNode level.  (Almost certainly your best bet is, quite simply, when you put a sprite in an SKScene, just call a function "setup()" which you have added to your sprites.)